# Rails - prepopulate textarea with existing attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, textarea

I have following situation:

I've got two models

- a Risk model with the attributes name, risk_class_id, description, level
- a Risk_Class model with the attributs name and description

A Risk has one Risk Class and a Risk Class has many Risks. This association works fine. I can assign a Risk Class to a Risk. To create a Risk I use the following form:

```
<%= form_for @risk, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
<div class="control-group">
  <%= f.label :name, :class => 'control-label' %>
  <div class="controls">
    <%= f.text_area :name, :class => 'text_area' %>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
  <%= f.label :risk_class_id, :class => 'control-label' %>
  <div class="controls">
    <%= collection_select( :risk, :risk_class_id, RiskClass.all, :id, :name, :prompt => true ) %>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
  <%= f.label :description, :class => 'control-label' %>
  <div class="controls">
    <%= f.text_area :description, :class => 'text_area' %>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
  <%= f.label :level, :class => 'control-label' %>
  <div class="controls">
    <%= f.text_area :level, :class => 'text_area' %>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.submit nil, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Now i would like to have that the textarea field for the description gets prepopulated based on the selected risk class, as a risk class has a description.

Thankful for any help!

EDIT

I've added following javascript code to the form and edited the collection select the following way:

```
<%= javascript_tag do %>
  function risk_class_selection(riskclassId){
    window.alert(riskclassId);
  } 
<% end %>
<div class="control-group">
  <%= f.label :risk_class_id, :class => 'control-label' %>
  <div class="controls">
    <%= collection_select( :risk, :risk_class_id, RiskClass.all, :id, :name, {:prompt => true} , {:onchange => "risk_class_selection(this.value)"}) %>
  </div>
</div>
```

SOLUTION:
in case anyone is interested i followed the way grotori described and my solution looks now like this:

I've got this risk.js file:

```
function risk_class_selection(riskclassId){
if (riskclassId != ""){
$.getJSON("/risk_classes/"+riskclassId+".json", function(data){
        if ( $('#risk_description').val() == "" ){
            $("#risk_description").val(data.description);
        }
        else{
            if ( confirm('Are you sure you want to change the risk description?') ){
                $("#risk_description").val(data.description);
            }
            else{
            }
        }
    }
)
}
else{}
}
```

And in the Risk Form i've got the first div with the onchange event and the second where the textarea should be prepopulated:

```
<div class="control-group">
  <%= f.label :risk_class_id, :class => 'control-label' %>
  <div class="controls">
    <%= collection_select( :risk, :risk_class_id, RiskClass.all, :id, :name, {:prompt => true} , {:onchange => "risk_class_selection(this.value)"}) %>
  </div>
</div>
    <div class="control-group">
  <%= f.label :description, :class => 'control-label' %>
  <div class="controls">
    <%= f.text_area :description, :class => 'text_area' %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must bind an onchange event to your select field that will post back to your server the user's selection and respond with javascript that will re-render the textarea with the desired value you want.

Comment: thx! i think your described solution is the way to go. I edited the question and added some javascript code.
could you help me a bit more with the javascript code? how do i have to change it that it re-renders the textarea?

Comment: You should checkout this http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2010/06/unobtrusive-javascript-in-rails-3/ It explains the general idea. In few words, on the "change" event, you have to make a $.ajax call with a valid url that will respond for example with a javascript that will replace the content of the text area. Caution, your controller's action that will be execute must respond_to format.js / format.json or whatever you decide.

Comment: thx again! :) followed your description and works now! pasted my working code above.

Comment: Great! I think rails should provide a more automatic way for this kind of stuff but...

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in controller when preparing the object @risk. Something like this:

```
@risk = Risk.new(description: "blah blah")
```

Then the form will have this value with `form_for` tag.

Comment: i don't think this would work.. may be there is a missunderstanding.. as the description should be set based on the selected risk class in the form, i can not do this in the controller because this is not based on the selection in the form.. do you understand what i mean?